# How to test Logger for single class using Spock?

Tags: java, logging, groovy, spock

So I have one class:

```
ExtractJustAddedObjectTypeIDsBolt {
      private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExtractJustAddedObjectTypeIDsBolt.class);

      public void someMethod() {
        logger.error("this is an error");
      }
}

ClassOneTest extends Specification {
    ExtractJustAddedObjectTypeIDsBolt bolt;

    void setup() { 
      this.bolt = new ExtractJustAddedObjectTypeIDsBolt();
    }

    void cleanup() { // run after every feature method

    }

    def "test someMethod"() {
      given:

      when:
      bolt.someMethod();

      then:
      bolt.logger.error("this is an error");
    }
}
```

But this is the error I get:

```
199  [main] ERROR member.bolt.ExtractJustAddedObjectTypeIDsBolt - this is an error

Too few invocations for:

1 * bolt.logger.error("this is an error")   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
   def "test someMethod"() {
      given:
          def logger = Mock(Logger)
      and:
          bolt.logger = logger
      when:
          bolt.someMethod()
      then:
          1 * logger.error("this is an error")
    }
```

You need to mock first the Logger.